# Getting HTML table data (td) (i.e. text or val) using table header (th) into Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, textarea

I have SQLite3 (i.e. Spatialite query) that outputs the results into HTML table. I want to get the AsText(Geometry) data to output in `<textarea>`

Here is the `table` and some assumptions.

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <th>name</th>
         <th>AsText(Geometry))</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Andres Street</td>
         <td>LINESTRING(7.120068 43.583917,7.120154 43.583652,7.120385 
          43.582716,7.12039 43.582568,7.120712 43.581511,7.120873 43.580718)</td>
    </tr>
</table>


$('#wktInput').click(function(){

???
???

     var asTextGeometryText =

    $("#wktResult").text(asTextGeometryText);
});




<textarea name='wktResult' value ='wktResult' ROWS="10" COLS="50" >'Should Display AsText(Geometry Column here!'</textarea>
```

This is the DOM

```
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    var fieldNames = aResult.fieldNames;
    var records = aResult.data;
    var numFields = fieldNames.length;
    var numRecords = records.length;
    var container = document.getElementById('queryResults');
    container.innerHTML = '';
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    container.appendChild(table);
    var headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
   table.appendChild(headerRow);
    for(var i = 0; i < numFields; i++){
        var header = document.createElement('th');
        header.innerText = fieldNames[i];
        headerRow.appendChild(header);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < numRecords; i++){
        var tableRow =  document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(tableRow);

        for(var j = 0; j < numFields; j++){
            var tableData = document.createElement('td');
            tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
            tableData.innerText = records[i][j];
        }
    }
}

<input id='SQLinput' size="90" rows="3" value = 'SELECT name, AsText(Geometry) FROM Roads Where MbrContains(Geometry, MakePoint(7.120872,43.580722,4326))'></input>

<input type='button' class='button' value='Display AsText' ontouchend='wktAsTextInput'/>
```

Thanks in advance

It seems that texarea uses id for value.

`<textarea id="field1">example text</textarea>`
[This problem is related to textarea in jQuery as well][1]

This example below demonstrate that jquery is not working in textarea using id.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var row = $('input:first').val();
        var column = $('input:eq(1)').val();
        var cell = $('table tr:eq('+row+') td:eq('+column+')');
        if (cell.length == 0) {
            $('#value').text('Undefined');
        }
        else {
            $('#value').text(cell.text());
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Table Cell Value</h1>
<table>
    <tr><td>Cell 1-1</td><td>Cell 1-2</td><td>Cell 1-3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 2-1</td><td>Cell 2-2</td><td>Cell 2-3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 3-1</td><td>Cell 3-2</td><td>Cell 3-3</td></tr>
</table>

Row: <input type="text" value="0">
Column: <input type="text" value="0">
Value: <span id="value">?</span><br>
Textarea: <textarea id="value" >Try this! this is not working</textarea>
<button>Get Value</button>
```

All is working in this example. Then added a textarea to see if I can make it work. Textarea is not working in this example. Something wrong with jquery and textarea using id as well as name.

`Textarea: <textarea name="value" >Try this! this is not work as well</textarea>`

How this does not work.

New info about this `textarea` value.

```
$('#id_of_textarea').attr('value'); //to get and...
$('#id_of_textarea').attr('value','updated value of textarea'); //to set it...

<textarea id="editor_desc" onkeyup="update_textarea(this)"></textarea>

function update_textarea(obj)
{
    $('#mydiv').text($(obj).attr('value')); //whatever you type in the textarea would be reflected in #mydiv
```

}

http://blog.ekini.net/2009/02/24/jquery-getting-the-latest-textvalue-inside-a-textarea/

It seems that my problem is not rendering a regular html tablet but a direct render to the screen.

The author of QuickConnect say told me,

> If you want one of those values so that you can use it you need to pull it
>   out of the 2D array.

Comment: please reformat your code to readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean displaying the content in AsText(Geometry) column at the textarea?

```
var text = []
$('table').find('tr:has(td)').each(function(){
    text.push($.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html()));
})
// and you set it to your textarea
$('textarea[name="wktResult"]').val(text.join('\n'));
```

Comment: You can touch the DOM. The DOM created for SQLite3 / Spatialite  Xcode bindings for iOS.

Comment: I want to only this. LINESTRING(7.120068 43.583917,7.120154 43.583652,7.120385 
          43.582716,7.12039 43.582568,7.120712 43.581511,7.120873 43.580718)

Comment: Again, the DOM part is SQLite3 / Spatialite Xcode bindings for iOS. DOM interact to the Webkit UI. You can not change it. It part of the Open Source QuickConnect iOS framework.

Comment: I did not work. If you want to see how the DOM implementation download the QuickConnect and look at the NativeDB example, junctions.js. This file is the link to the Xcode iOS bindings. Here the link http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickconnect/

Comment: I should mention that the query renders the table properly. I need to get the LINESTRING data as input to be parse into WKT for OpenLayers mapping toolkit. The sequence of events are: query, get the LINESTRING and put it in Textarea. Parse the textarea text for rendering into the Openlayer map canvas.

Comment: This is the query, SELECT name, AsText(Geometry) FROM Roads Where MbrContains(Geometry, MakePoint(7.120872,43.580722,4326))

Comment: $('textarea[name="wktResult"]').val(text.join('\n')); This line got a parser error.

Comment: You just want the content of that column, right? then set text = [] and the beginning. and about your parser error.. can you provide more clue? I don't see any error around this statement.

Comment: $('#wktInput').click(function(){
   var text = []
   $('table').find('tr:has(td)').each(function(){
    text.push($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html());
    }
// and you set it to your textarea
   $('textarea[name="wktResult"]').val(text.join('\n'));
  });

Comment: Hi ns-1m, it should be ok now. :)

Comment: Did you edit your answer to reflect this? It seems that there is a problem textarea with id to get value in jquery. I have small example above in which textarea does not work. I will edit the original post and put this example.

Comment: Liangliang Zheng, I think I find the solution using attr in this post [link] (http://blog.ekini.net/2009/02/24/jquery-getting-the-latest-textvalue-inside-a-textarea/) $('#id_of_textarea').attr('value'); Kindly edited your answer and incorporated this. Thanks.

Comment: It seems this is jquery problem only. It also javascript. [link](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3660758.htm). Still not working. I don't know how to use this document.getElementById("textarea-id").value = myVar;

Comment: @ns-1m: first, I guess it would possibly be the problem of trimming.

Comment: @ns-1m:second, I have try this code. It seems ok to me, so please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/3tEEa/

Comment: Some promising but I got Syntax error: parser error. Since the code is not complete. It need a button to click to check it. I got this code which is not working.<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('button').click(function() {
 
    var text = []
   $('table').find('tr:has(td)').each(function(){
       text.push($.trim($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html()));
    
    // and you set it to your textarea
    $('textarea[name="wktResult"]').val(text.join('\n'));
      
 });
     
</script>

Comment: Liangliang Zheng, It works now, the example you provided. I need to apply it to my project. Thanks a lot for helping me to solve this problem. I'll update when it is working on the my project.

Comment: It did not work in the actual project. The table has a container -- var container = document.getElementById('queryResults');
It seems that it is not finding the table. How do we included the container information in your code.

Comment: The table is a container?? Can you try $('#queryResults') or $('#queryResults table') ? It sounds like your table is the container, right?

Comment: I think it is not. Just look at the DOM that I posted. I tried the options that you suggested above and still it is not working. I could not get any text in the textarea. Any suggestion how we can manipulate the DOM element to get the AsText(Geometry) column into a textarea?

Comment: It seems that the output of queryResults is not really a tablet as a hint from the author of QuickConnect. "If you want one of those values so that you can use it you need to pull it out of the 2D array." I will edit the question about post the DOM to be manupulated.

Comment: Liangliang Zheng, I created a new question since this is getting complicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393080/creating-a-dom-for-textarea-from-sql-queries-table-result

Answer (score 0):

1- assign an id attribute to your textarea to use it in jquery or if your page contain just one textarea you can use tag name insteasd.

2- to get text of textarea you need just call text function without any parameters

```
$('#wktInput').click(function(){
     var asTextGeometryText =$('table').find('th').eq(2).text();
     $('#id_of_textarea').attr('value',asTextGeometryText);
});
```

Comment: $('#wktInput').click(function(){
     var asTextGeometryText =$('table').find('th').eq(2).text();
     $('wktResult').text(asTextGeometryText);
});
<input type='button' class='button' value='Display AsText' ontouchend='wktInput'/>           
           
 <textarea id='wktResult' ROWS="10" COLS="50" >'Should Display AsText(Geometry Column here!'</textarea>

Comment: $('#wktInput').click(function () {
        var asTextGeometryText = $('table').find('th').eq(1).text();
        $('textarea').val(asTextGeometryText);
    });

Comment: No. I did not work. No matter if I change the 'textarea' to wktResult or use textarea as <textarea id=textarea .....

Comment: if you will use id of your `textarea` tag, you must prefix it with `#`

Comment: $('#wktInput').click(function () { var asTextGeometryText = $('table').find('th').eq(1).text(); $('wktResult').val(asTextGeometryText); }); <textarea id='#wktResult' ROWS="10" COLS="50" >'Should Display AsText(Geometry Column here!'</textarea> This one did not work as well.

Comment: Miroprocessor, could you update your answer based on this info [link](http://blog.ekini.net/2009/02/24/jquery-getting-the-latest-textvalue-inside-a-textarea/) on $('#id_of_textarea').attr('value');

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer. I am very sure this one works with regular html render. However, I told by the author of the framework that I am using (i.e. QuickConnect for iOS) that tablet renders into the screen is not a html render. Although it uses DOM html to communicate to javascript and jquery yet the render might be native render. I am puzzle with screen render.